# ввод нескольких строк в одну переменную

Tags: python, переменные

Вот в чем проблема. Есть ли в Пайтоне способ вводить неограниченное количество строк через Enter в одну и ту же переменную кроме sys.stdin? В задании сказано сделать его[задание] с использованием всего одной строки, но для того, что бы вводить sys.stdin сначала нужно прописат import sys.stdin

Comment: `__import__('sys').stdin.readlines()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строку:

```
x = '\n'.join(i for i in iter(input, ''))
```

или в список:

```
x = [i for i in iter(input, '')]
```

Comment: не против правки?

Comment: @eri в целом не против, только у автора вопроса нет ничего про то, что результат должен быть сохранён именно в строку, а не в список.

Comment: давай тогда оба варианта оставим...

Comment: Все работает, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Можно:

```
s = ''
for line in iter(input, ''): s = s + "\n" + line
```

Ввод прекратится после двух подряд нажатий на Enter.

Comment: Это три строки.

Comment: Да. Недопонял задание.

Comment: причем с ошибкой)

Comment: @eri всё работает

Comment: @Эникейщик а точка с запятой обычно считается читерством)

Comment: Если всё работает - это не значит что ошибки нет)

Comment: @andreymal это не я 

Comment: @andreymal это я поставил)

Comment: @Эникейщик второй аргумент для итер это условие выхода из цикла. а не исходная переменная

Comment: @eri вариант Эникейщика работает, а ваш invalid syntax выдаёт. Давайте не делать правки, противоречащие намерениям автора?

Comment: окей.. можно както удалить правку?

Comment: после отката морда моя так и остается...

Comment: Но `s)`, наверно, действительно логичнее заменить на `'')`